# Apex Class for VF Component Error Missing return statement required return type: String (37:19)

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

I am trying to create a class that feeds logic into a component for a Visualforce Email Template.

```
public String getBillingContact() {

    CaseContactRelation__c ccRelation = 
                             [
                             SELECT Id, ContactId__c, ContactId__r.AccountId, ContactId__r.Account.Name
                             FROM CaseContactRelation__c
                             WHERE Roles__c != 'Requester' AND CaseId__c =:targetObjectId LIMIT 1
                            ][0];

    String cBillingContact = '';
    if (ccRelation.ContactId__r.Account.Name != null) {
        cBillingContact = ccRelation.ContactId__r.Account.Name;
    }


}
```

I don't come from a technical background so am struggling to resolve the issue that has croppped up, I don't even know where to start.

> Missing return statement required return type: String (37:19)

If anyone has any ideas they would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those cases where the error correctly tells you what the issue is.

```apex
public String getBillingContact()
       ^^^^^^
```

This is the *return type* which is the part of a method definition indicates what the method returns (if anything - the *return type* could be `void` which does not return anything) to the code that calls this method.

So somewhere in the body of the method, usually after the method does its work, you have to have a line (a.k.a. *statement*) that returns something of that *return type*.

In your case the method needs to return a `String`.  There are multiple ways to do this.

It could literally do...

```apex
return '';
```

...or...

```apex
return 'Some string';
```

...but that would *always* return the same thing every time the method was called, which I would confidently say that is not what this method should do.

---

Usually somewhere at or near the beginning of a method, a variable of the *return type* is created which will hold the value to be returned, and then that variable is used in the `return` *statement*.  It seems in your method there is:

```apex
String cBillingContact = '';
```

So at the end your method could simply have...

```apex
return cBillingContact;
```

...which would fulfill the technical requirement that your error is indicating.

Whether that `cBillingContact` variable holds the correct or expected value is a different question and is not guaranteed by merely satisfying the technical requirement.

---

If you are going to need to even just dip your toes in Apex, you should really go to Salesforce Trailhead (https://trailhead.salesforce.com) and do some of the Apex basics modules/trails.  There are some geared toward Admins who want or need to know some Apex basics.  Trailhead is free - you just need to create a free acccount.

Comment: That was an awesome explanation and incredibly helpful, thank you. This snippet - return cBillingContact; - seemed to satusfy all requirements.